# SQL Developer error reporting -- wrong line numbers

Tags: debugging, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm tasked with writing and testing several small PL/SQL scripts. It's way outside my core competency, but I can do it with enough trial and error. One thing that complicates this process is the error reporting of SQ LDeveloper. It outputs a short description of the problem with a line and column number, but the line number bears no relation to where the error actually is. That is, I might have used = instead of := for assignment on line 52 of my script, but the error in the Script Output window says the problem in on line 37. In that a typical problem? Is there a way of converting the reported line number to an actual one?

I'm using SQL Developer 1.5.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know what you mean. I come across this issue on a daily basis. I still haven't totally figured out the exact solution but it seems to have something to do with how the compiler handles comments. I just did a test on my machine using a query where I inserted an error on a particular line. The Error at Line: # was off as expected. After removing the commented lines from the SQL the error corresponded to the Line #.

Edit: Adding test case in response to Ian Carpenter

```
select column1
       ,column2
--       ,column3
       ,column4
from table1
where 1=1
and column1 = '00000000';
```

Run then change to:

```
select column1
       ,column2
--       ,column3
       ,column4a
from table1
where 1=1
and column1 = '00000000';
```

Run and get following error:

```
ORA-00904: "COLUMN4A": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 11
```

Comment: I see the problem, if you run it as a script (F5) I believe it reports the correct line? However a quick look on the SQL Developer Oracle Technology Network forums shows lots of issues with the line number being incorrectly reported

Comment: @IanCarpenter Ah. Thanks for the tip. I didn't think to try run as script. Hmm. It may have something to do with how F9 sends the SQL to the database. IIRC Statements are submitted like SQLPlus commands. Scripts might be compiled and sent like PL/SQL block statements? Anyway, I'm just guessing here. I'll have to read up more on Run Statement versus Run Script. Oh, and sorry about misspelling your name earlier. I've corrected my answer.